# How to use variables as pivot columns on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, dynamic-columns, dynamic-tables

I am having an issue making a table with pivot columns more dynamic on MS SQL Server.

I have a query that retrieves data from a five week period of the current year and a five week period of the previous year, so the columns CUR_YR and PREV_YR are the ones that come from the pivot clause. This is my query:

```
DECLARE @TODAY DATE
SET @TODAY= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
DECLARE @PREV_YR INT, @CUR_YR INT
SET @CUR_YR = YEAR(@TODAY)
SET @PREV_YR = @CUR_YR-1

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT BUS, DET, [STR], COALESCE(@PREV_YR,0) AS PREV_YR, COALESCE(@CUR_YR,0) AS CUR_YR FROM (
        SELECT YR,BUS, DET,[STR],count(ORD_ID_SE) as ORDS FROM (<SUBQUERY>) )AS T
PIVOT(
    SUM(ORDS)
    FOR YR IN (
            @PREV_YR, @CUR_YR)
) AS pivot_table
)AS F
```

When ever I manually set the pivot columns inside the FOR YR IN() clause as 2020 and 2021, the query works, but since I need these columns to be dynamic (aka. make them change as time goes on, so next year they are 2021 and 2022) I use the variables @PREV_YR and @CUR_YR as shown in the code. However, this results in the error "Incorrect syntax near '@PREV_YR'.".

Is there a work around for this? Maybe a different way to feed the two years inside the IN() clause.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can do it with dynamic SQL.  But the best solution would be to do this kind of transformations in your presentation layer.

Comment: Do you *have to* have the column names dynamic, or can we just call them `CurrentYear, PreviousYear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation of the PIVOT functionality. You must have a pre-defined set of columns within your `IN` list. They can not change dynamically. So in order to do this you would need to utilize dynamic SQL to change your result set based on your input values.

There are many guides on how to do this out there, but I will give an example of how you could apply it to your script (with some minor reformatting added). I did correct two issues in order to run it. 1.Add alias to your subquery `subquery_alias` 2. Add `GROUP BY` clause to your aggregate query

```
DECLARE @TODAY DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE); 
DECLARE @CUR_YR INT = YEAR(@TODAY); 
DECLARE @PREV_YR INT = @CUR_YR-1; 
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) =
N'SELECT    
    * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        BUS
        ,DET
        ,[STR]
        ,COALESCE(' + QUOTENAME(CAST(@PREV_YR AS nvarchar(10))) + N',0) AS PREV_YR
        ,COALESCE(' + QUOTENAME(CAST(@CUR_YR AS nvarchar(10))) + N',0) AS CUR_YR 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
            YR
            ,BUS
            ,DET
            ,[STR]
            ,COUNT(ORD_ID_SE) AS ORDS 
        FROM 
            (<SUBQUERY>) AS subquery_alias
        GROUP BY 
            YR
            ,BUS
            ,DET
            ,[STR]) AS T
PIVOT(SUM(ORDS) FOR YR IN (' + QUOTENAME(CAST(@PREV_YR AS nvarchar(10))) + N',' + QUOTENAME(CAST(@CUR_YR AS nvarchar(10))) + N')) AS pivot_table) AS F'; 

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Sql;
```

That being said, in this case you are re-aliasing the output of your pivot tables to be `PREV_YR` and `CUR_YR` respectively. So you really don't need dynamic column names and if you are only ever going to use two different variables in this manner then it makes more sense to pivot it with a `SUM(CASE WHEN....END)` method. Like so:

```
DECLARE @TODAY DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE); 
DECLARE @CUR_YR INT = YEAR(@TODAY); 
DECLARE @PREV_YR INT = @CUR_YR-1; 
SELECT  
    BUS
    ,DET
    ,[STR]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN YR = @PREV_YR THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PREV_YR
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN YR = @CUR_YR THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CUR_YR
FROM 
    (<SUBQUERY>) AS subquery_alias
GROUP BY 
    BUS
    ,DET
    ,[STR];
```

Doing this you can completely avoid dynamic SQL and a more complicated pivot query.

Comment: It's not a limitation in `PIVOT` per se, it's a limitation in SQL that all columns need to be predefined

Comment: @Charlieface true.  I was trying to keep in terms of this discussion, but perhaps a better description for my post might have been 'a common wishful thought for the PIVOT functionality' :)

Comment: Not really possible to even conceptualize if you know anything about SQL. People want it because it looks pretty in Excel, but it is a fundamental misunderstanding about what a column represents. A column name is not data, it defines what the data represents, so data does not belong in there. These kinds of pivots should be done in the presentation layer

Comment: @Charlieface I understand this. Hence my recommendation that he doesn't utilize a dynamic pivot, but instead uses the second, equivalent query that I posted which would be more in line with relational principles. Using SQL to pivot your data with columns like CurrentYear or PreviousYear (as recommended in your comment on OP) is what I am directing him to do as well.

Comment: I had no idea that there was a simpler option for the PIVOT statement. I only had to make a small adjustment_ "SUM(CASE WHEN YR = @PREV_YR THEN ORDS ELSE 0 END) ", otherwise I only ever got 0 and 1 on my year columns. Thank you very much for this solution

Comment: @JCarNav glad that worked for you! If this answered your question then please mark it as the accepted answer.